# Installed blender version 2.92 and 2.91.2 but when it launch is shows not responding please help

Tags: windows

Device name RHINOCEROS
Processor   AMD A4-9125 RADEON R3, 4 COMPUTE CORES 2C+2G      2.30 GHz
Installed RAM   4.00 GB (3.89 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎2/‎28/‎2021
OS build    19042.844
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
[image]Pen and touch    No pen or touch input is available for this display i updated the system and all drivers and i waited for a very long time but its still stuck in not responding im waiting right now still not coming up

Comment: This sounds like more of a bug report. But anyway, how long did you wait for the window to unfreeze?

Comment: That is kind of weird. I don’t know what’s going on, but on my computer blender opens just fine. Do you have any odd configuration settings, or has this computer been modified in anyway?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then re-downloading and reinstalling blender? I had a really funny glitch one time, but it turned out to be a one in 1 million download mistake that had given me an erroneous executable.